# React Navigation on tab change

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Without using Redux, how do I detect a tab change with a react navigation tab navigator?

I know I need to somehow use onNavigationStateChange but I can't figure out how to update the current view.

```js
export default () => <MyTabNav
    ref={(ref) => { this.nav = ref; }}
    onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
        //call function on current view
    }}
/>;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
export default () => <MyTabNav
    ref={(ref) => { this.nav = ref; }}
    onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
       const getCurrentRouteName = (navigationState) => {
         if (!navigationState) return null;
         const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
         if (route.routes) return getCurrentRouteName(route);
         return route.routeName;
       };
    global.currentRoute = getCurrentRouteName(currentState);
  }}
/>;
```

If you don't want to use redux, this is how you can store global information about the current route, so you can both detect a tab change and also tell which tab is now active.

Answer (score 36):

Actually, you can add an special listener in your component

```js
componentDidMount () {
    this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', (route) => { //tab changed });
}
```

Comment: {//tab changed} what do I need to write here I have taken 4 tabs Home, Profile, Example, Currents.

Comment: This is not correct, if the tab itself is a StackNavigator, poping will also cause the screen to focus.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) version **5** or higher, then you can add `tab-press` listener right in your tab screen definition, to do some pre-processing, as mentioned in [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#listeners-prop-on-screen)

```js
<Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen
        component={HomeScreen}
        name="HomeScreen"
        listeners={{
          tabPress: e => {
            if (userIsNotLoggedIn) {
              // Prevent default action
              e.preventDefault();
              navigation.navigate("LoginScreen");
            }
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        ../>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

**Explanation**: When `Home` tab will be clicked in `BottomBar`, and if user is not logged in, the `HomeScreen` won't open and instead `LoginScreen` will open(Note: `LoginScreen` is navigation name which will be registered some where with a screen). But if user is logged in, then it will behave normally.

As of react-navigation v6, you may also place a `tabPress` listener on the `<Tab.Navigator>`, via the `screenListeners` property.

Comment: tabPress is not recognized as a listener for me?

Comment: Which react-navigation version you are using? I'm using `v5.4.2` and it's working fine

Comment: Version: "react-navigation": "4.4.1"
"@react-navigation/native": "5.7.5"

Comment: @user1804084 when you use `react-navigation` v5, you use the library `@react-navigation/native`, and it will be obviously greater than v5, so I don't understand how you can mix match v4 with v5

Answer (score 5):

There's some long discussions about this from react-native issue [314](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/314), [486](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/486), [1335](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/1335), and finally we got a better built in way to handle this, after Sep 27, 2017, react-navigation version [v1.0.0-beta.13](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/releases):

> ### New Features
>
> Accept a tabBarOnPress param (#1335) - @cooperka

**Usage:**

```js
const MyTabs = TabNavigator({
  ...
}, {
  tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom /* or TabBarTop */,
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom' /* or 'top' */,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {
      console.log('onPress:', scene.route);
      jumpToIndex(scene.index);
    },
  }),
});
```

Comment: Does this get called when navigating via other means (e.g. swiping between screens if that's enabled, or by invoking navigation actions programmatically)?

Comment: `jumpToIndex` doesn't work for me thus I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53634195/911408)

Answer (score 1):

And if you intend to use the `Window` properties, you can easily do this in react.

Keep a check whether `window` is present before `return` inside of `render`.

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
window.addEventListener('visibilitychange, () => {
window.document.title = window.document.hidden;
console.log(document.hidden ? "Out" : "In");
this.props.doFunction();
```

}