# how to use tabBarOnPress in tabnavigator react native

Tags: react-native

i am stuck in big problem that is i wants onPress event when i clicked on tab.
my code is here:-

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation, screenProps}) => {
   const params = navigation.state.params || {};
   console.log("Params:-",params);
  return {
        title:Strings.title_dashboard,
        headerStyle:{ backgroundColor: Colors.header_blue},
        headerTitleStyle:HeaderStyle.titleCenter,
        tabBarOnPress: (tab, jumpToIndex) => {
           console.log("Tab Click",tab);
            jumpToIndex(tab.index);
            navigation.state.params.onFocus()
        },
       headerRight:<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>Alert.alert(Strings.avanza,Strings.under_imple)}><View><Image source={{uri: "filter_icon"}} style={{height: 18, width: 18,marginRight:10,}} /></View></TouchableOpacity>,
  }
  }
```

at here i set the Params like this in componentDidMount:

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({
      handleGrid: this.callServer.bind(this)
    })
```

getting an error here not able to get this click event.

Help me please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

This is my approach. It works for the version 5.x.x of react-navigation:

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Tabs = props => (
  <BottomTab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Foo"
    ...
    <BottomTab.Screen
      name="Foo"
      component={Foo}
      initialParams={props.route.params}
      listeners={{
        tabPress: e => {
          // e.preventDefault(); // Use this to navigate somewhere else
          console.log("Foo tab bar button pressed")
        },
      }}
    />
  </BottomTab.Navigator>
);
```

Read more about [listeners](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/).

---

For version 3.x.x and I hope for the 4th as well please use this one.

```
let Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    FooTab: Foo,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "FooTab",
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
        console.log('onPress:', navigation.state.routeName);
        defaultHandler()
      },
    }),
  }
);
```

---

For version 2.x.x please use `navigationOptions` instead of the `defaultNavigationOptions`.

Comment: But how to get the value for navigation.state.routeName?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal, in the example above "FooTab" is the value for the `navigation.state.routeName`

Comment: By using your code I am getting only 'onPress' in log not the routename

Comment: I've just copy pasted this code in my app and it works. What version of the react-navigation do you have?

Comment: @VladimirVlasov I have 3.3.2 version and it doesn't work. What is your version?

Comment: @dakiesse I've just updated the answer. I used the previous major version of the react-navigation and I updated it today in my project.

Comment: Even I am following the same but its not working. Also, if I print alert('message') inside tabBarOnPress, it creates alert only for first time. After reloading the app for second or more time, even alert also don't work.

Comment: This solution worked for me as I wanted to disable routing to a screen but have the tab icon present , so I just commented out the defaulthandler

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me,

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
       return {
            tabBarOnPress: ({previousScene, scene, jumpToIndex}) => {
                const { route, index, focused} = scene;

                if(focused){
                    navigation.state.params.scrollToTop()
                }
                jumpToIndex(0)
            }
        }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

I used stack navigator

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator({
    ScreenA: {
        screen:ScreenA ,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
            header: null
        }),
    },
    ScreenB: {
        screen:ScreenB ,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
            header: null
        }),
    },
});
```

//Added tabBarOnPress

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html
the popToTop action takes you back to the first screen in the stack, dismissing all the others. It's functionally identical to StackActions.pop({n: currentIndex}).

```
import { StackActions } from 'react-navigation';
let Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    FooTab: Foo,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "FooTab",
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
      // to navigate to the top of stack whenever tab changes
      navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
      defaultHandler();
      ]},
    }),
  }
);
```