# React native listen to tab change from component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible in React Native to listen to a tab change in component?

```
  useEffect(() => {

    return () => console.log('unmount?')
  }, [navigation])
```

is there anything I can put in use effect that would detect when I change tab and leave the component. I guess it hasn't unmounted but I need to know when the user has left the screen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000640/react-navigation-on-tab-change/50893668 ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use**

```
navigation.isFocused
```

to know which screen is focussed

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/), that on return receives the blur function:

```
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const unsubscribe = API.subscribe(userId, user => setUser(user)); // onFocus

      return () => unsubscribe(); // onBlur
    }, [userId])
  );
```